# How to display recommendations after calculating a certain result?

Tags: javascript

How do I display something like a recommendation list after a user calculate a result from the inputs? E.g having the user to key in the salaries of the family and calculating the PCI (Per capita income) and after they key in and press on the calculate button which then will trigger a list of recommendations based on the amount of PCI the family have (Maybe tables that shows different results based on different categories of PCI?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script>
    function cal()
    {
        var salary1 = document.getElementById('salary1').value;
        var salary2 = document.getElementById('salary2').value;
        var salary3 = document.getElementById('salary3').value;
        var salary4 = document.getElementById('salary4').value;
        var members = document.getElementById('members').value;


        var total = (parseInt(salary1) + parseInt(salary2) + parseInt(salary3) + parseInt(salary4)) / parseInt(members);
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;

        alert (total);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Want to know which bursary your eligible?</h1>
<input id="salary1" value="" placeholder="Enter your 1st family income..."/>
<input id="salary2" value="" placeholder="Enter your 2nd family income..."/>
<input id="salary3" value="" placeholder="Enter your 3rd family income..."/>
<input id="salary4" value="" placeholder="Enter your 4th family income..."/>
<input id="members" value="" placeholder="Enter the total number of family members..."/>
<br>
<button onclick="cal()"> Calculate PCI!</button>
<br>
Total: <input id="total"> </input>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden div that holds the data then show that div when user clicks the button

HTML:

```
   <div id="divToShow"  style="display:none;" class="table_list" > 
   //put your data table here
   </div>

   <input type="button" name="myButton" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('divToShow').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3yrkmbr/2/).

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="number1" type="number" min="1" name="number" placholder="add value one"> + 
  <input id="number2" type="number" min="1" name="number" placholder="add value one">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
    number1 = document.getElementById('number1');
    number2 = document.getElementById('number2');
form.onsubmit = function() {
   var total = +number1.value + +number2.value; // add + before 
   alert( total );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     function cal(){
var salary1 = document.getElementById('salary1').value;
        var salary2 = document.getElementById('salary2').value;
        var salary3 = document.getElementById('salary3').value;
        var salary4 = document.getElementById('salary4').value;
        var members = document.getElementById('members').value;
        var recommanted;
        var recommandations=[
        {maxpci:1000,recommandation:'first_recommandation'},
        {maxpci:2000,recommandation:'second_recommandation'},
        {maxpci:3000,recommandation:'third_recommandation'},
        {maxpci:6000,recommandation:'fourth_recommandation'}
        ];

        var total=(parseInt(salary1) + parseInt(salary2) + parseInt(salary3) + parseInt(salary4)) / parseInt(members);



        if(recommandations[recommandations.length - 1].maxpci < total ){recommanted=recommandations[recommandations.length - 1].recommandation;}
        else{
        for (var i = 0; i < recommandations.length; i++) {
        if(total <= recommandations[i].maxpci){

        recommanted=recommandations[i].recommandation;break;}

        }}


        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your PCI : "+total+"</br>Recommandation : "+recommanted;
}
```

```html
    <h1>Want to know which bursary your eligible?</h1>
    <input id="salary1" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter your 1st family income..."/>
    <input id="salary2" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter your 2nd family income..."/>
    <input id="salary3" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter your 3rd family income..."/>
    <input id="salary4" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter your 4th family income..."/>
    <input id="members" type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter the total number of family members..."/>
    </br>
    <button onclick="cal()"> Calculate PCI!</button>
    </br>
        <div id="result">

        </div>
```

Comment: When answering a question it's always a good idea to explain the problem/solution instead of just posting a block of code.